# mysql match against russain

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, match

Trying to solve this for a very long time now...

```
SELECT MATCH(name) AGAINST('абраксас')
```

(russian) doesn't work, but

```
SELECT MATCH(name) AGAINST('abraxas')
```

(english) work perfectly.
I know it's something with character-set, but I tried all kind of settings and it didn't work.
For now it's latin-1.
LIKE works
This is the `show variables` charset related:

```
character_set_client - latin1
character_set_connection - latin1
character_set_database - latin1
character_set_filesystem - binary
character_set_results - latin1
character_set_server - latin1
character_set_system - utf8
character_sets_dir - /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
collation_connection - latin1_swedish_ci
collation_database - latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server - latin1_swedish_ci
```

chunk of /etc/my.cnf

```
default-character-set=latin1
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

chunk of the dump:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `scenes_raw`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `scenes_raw` (
`scene_name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
...blabla...
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=901 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

(I did tests without skip-character-set-client-handshake too)

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'scenes_raw'\G
Name: scenes_raw
Engine: MyISAM
Version: 10
Row_format: Dynamic
Index_length: 23552
Collation: utf8_general_ci
Checksum: NULL
Create_options:
```

Comment: Would it be possible to post a small snippet of the dump that shows the relevant parts?

Comment: Yep, done, in the body of the question.

Comment: Does the Hebrew string 'ססקרבא' encoded in UTF-8? e.g. if the script runs from a file - the file should be UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Yes: `file dump.sql  dump.sql: UTF-8 Unicode C program text, with very long lines`

Comment: actually in russian it stopped working too now :(

Comment: Do any of those entries appear >50% of the time in the table (that is, does "абраксас" appear in more than half the rows?) Also, do you have at least 3 rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting your character_set_client to UTF-8. I just tried it out:

```
> mysql -u root -p charset_test --default-character-set=latin1
mysql> select * from scenes_raw where MATCH(scene_name) AGAINST('абраксас');
Empty set (0.00 sec)

> mysql -u root -p charset_test --default-character-set=utf8
mysql> select * from scenes_raw where MATCH(scene_name) AGAINST('абраксас');
+------------------+
| scene_name       |
+------------------+
| абраксас         | 
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Edit: For more details, see [this explanation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_client) The "character_set_client" from your "SHOW VARIABLES" output is the character set your MySQL client is using to send to the server. When it is in Latin-1, it does not support Cyrillic, but when it is UTF-8, it should work fine.

Comment: Ok, I had default-character-set=latin1 and skip-character-set-client-handshake in my.cnf, which is not ok of course, but now I have a problem that the text in dump is gibberish when I use charset=utf8, and as far as I remember it's a lot of pain to convert it to utf all at once :( bummer, thanks for help though, it's not the final solution for me but it helped to find the source of the problem...

Comment: What's weird is that in dump file it seems utf8, and all the collations etc are utf8... but the text itself is latin1, very confused :/

Comment: buddy, u'r a god! i've been looking for the solution for years :)

Answer (score 0):

try to call **set names 'utf8'** once you open a connection to the server.

Comment: nope, it messes the encoding of the result and the score is still 0 :(

Comment: are you sure your data (both on db and on the queries) is actually in utf8?

Comment: well, in dump it shows DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 and LIKE works... so I guess it is :)